# Node.js server pain to handle 200 request per second

Tags: node.js, performance

I ran Jmeter load test on a simple GET route with this settings :

[load settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Z6W.png)

This route only select 1 entity by select-where statment on database (Postgres) (through typeORM) and then, return response.

```
async function checkIfCodeExist(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    const codeOnline = req.params.codeOnline as string;

    const session = await sessionInformationRepository.findOneBy({
        codeOnline,
    });

    if (null === session) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
        return;
    }

    res.sendStatus(204); 
}
```

Repository code :

```
const findOneBy = async (
    args: FindSessionByParams
): Promise<SessionInformation | null> => {
    const session = await SessionEntity.findOneBy({
        ...omitBy(args, (v) => null == v),
    });

    if (!session) {
        return null;
    }
    return convertToSessionInformation(session as SessionEntity);
};
```

Converter code :

```
//There is no endless recursive loop between converters
//Only 1 level of dependencies is actually loaded by ORM
//so that avoid "endless circular relations"
//Eg: Loaded session has "participants" mapped property
//These participants entities will not have "session" property loaded
export const convertToSessionInformation = (
    entity: SessionEntity
): SessionInformation => {
    return omitBy(
        {
            ...entity,
            startAt: entity.startAt ? entity.startAt.toISOString() : null,
            endAt: entity.endAt ? entity.endAt.toISOString() : null,
            participants:
                entity.participants && entity.participants.length
                    ? convertToListOfOnlineParticipant(entity.participants)
                    : undefined,
            vote: entity.vote
                ? {
                      ...entity.vote,
                      dateEnvoi: entity.vote?.dateEnvoi
                          ? moment(entity.vote?.dateEnvoi).toDate()
                          : undefined,
                  }
                : null,
        } as unknown as SessionInformation,
        (v) => undefined === v
    );
};
```

Results :

[load test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE5bZ.png)

Node.js log on errors : `{"msg":"The server is too busy, dropping the request","time":"2023-07-26T06:18:38.634Z"}`

Comes from : https://www.npmjs.com/package/toobusy-js.
(We use it without any custom settings).

Nodejs server
Framework: Express
Os: debian
vCPU: 16
Ram: 8Go
Cluster: no.
pm2 usage

Postgres server
Os: debian
vCPU: 5
Ram: 4Gb
Cluster: no.

According to : https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-many-requests-can-handle-a-real-world-nodejs-server-side-application

I should not have so poor performances, what do you think about it ?

Comment: can you share the code behind `sessionInformationRepository`, it could be something related with the database connection

Comment: Yes i'll edit the post

Comment: How many requests are handled it you don't query the database but just return a response from the server?

Comment: around 1/2k (performance may "randomly"
 vary)

Comment: last : 3k requests; 24s; 9.30% error (502 timeout)

Comment: If you handle 200 request per second (which is LOT) it means average processing time of request is 5ms (which is not a lot at all). So there are 2 options, use cache if it is possible (redis for example) to make it easier for the database, or use cluster of APIs with loadbalancer (you also need larger pool for posgtres because you would have multiple express instances)

Comment: what are your expected results btw?

Comment: Really ? according to some benchmarks found (such as the shared one in my post) i thaugh the performances were juste poor..